# Sentence with comparison

Tags: comparative-constructions

There's a thought that needs to be constructed into a sentence, but I am finding it difficult to string the words together. The intended sentence, ***if I am not mistaken***, is comparative in nature.

The muddled thought/idea is as follows:

> He behaves the same when he is drunk like he behaves when he is sober.

As you can see, I am not very good at constructing these kind of sentences. If you could please help me find the correct structure for the sentence above, I would really appreciate it.

Further, if possible, could you tell me what this kind of error is called, in grammatical terms? I'd really like to be able to form these type of sentences on my own.

Comment: "...behaves the **same** when he is drunk **as** *he behaves* when he is sober." The phrase in italics can be omitted.

Comment: You can even leave out *when he is* and thus shorten it to *He behaves the same drunk as sober.*

Comment: You can also use *does* to avoid duplicating the verb: *He behaves the same when he's drunk as he does [when he's] sober.* And you can omit the bracketed words.

Comment: Of course in conversation you might find yourself saying: "Yeah, he's always the same, drunk or sober."

Answer (score 1):

Whether drunk or sober, he behaves the same. OR He behaves the same whether he is drunk or sober.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is *the same as*, not *the same like*. You can say any of these:

- *X is the same as Y* (or *X behaves the same as Y* or *X sings the same as Y* etc.)
- *X is similar to Y* (or *X behaves similarly to Y* etc.)
- *X is like Y* (or *X behaves like Y* etc.)

It is not correct to say *X is the same like Y* (or *X behaves the same like Y* etc.)